# nhibernate composite primary key

Tags: c#, xml, nhibernate, app-config

i have a problem with the composite primary key:
i have a table named "simulateur", the composite primary key are Nombre_simulateur and Date 
 class simulateur.hbm.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true">
  <class name="base_donnee.simulateur, base_donnee" table="simulateur">
 <composite-id >
 <key-property name="Nombre_simulateur">
        <column name="[Nombre_simulateur]" sql-type="int" />
      </key-property>
      <key-property name="Date">
        <column name="[Date]" sql-type="nvarchar(50)" />
      </key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="temps_connection" type="int" />
    <property name="temps_envoi" type="int" />
    <property name="temps_reception" type="int" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

but an exception appears : Could not compile the mapping document: base_donnee.simulateur.hbm.xml ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find the dialect in the configuration

my file App.config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate"/>
  </configSections>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string_name">Northwind</property>
      <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
      <mapping assembly="base_donnee"/>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Northwind" connectionString="Data Source=HP-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Simulation; Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

i need help, any ideas?

Comment: seems like something wrong with your configuration, you could make sure that by converting composite id to a single id column, and trying to execute your program

Comment: if i converted it, it works but i am obliged to make the key composite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be missing the `connection.driver_class`

Add the following to your web.config:-

```
...
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
...
```

Comment: no it didn't work,because the driver is here:<add name="Northwind" connectionString="Data Source=HP-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Simulation; Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>